# Visual Studio format document occasionally breaks on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

For some reason, sometimes Visual Studio seems to mess up its own internal syntax tree (or whatever it's implemented as) for JavaScript files. Running "Format Document" yields completely broken formatting, like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I can't make this go away without restarting the entire IDE. Any ideas what I can do?

EDIT: And after a while, VS just admits it can't handle it by showing this popup dialog:

[image: The JavaScript language service has encountered an error and has been shut down. Please save your changes, exit, and restart Visual Studio.]

Comment: I wouldn't put it by Visual Studio to do something like that, but have you verified that it is syntactically correct?

Comment: @Neil: Yeah, it's fine! It's really strange. This happens from time to time. After restarting VS, doing "Format Document" works as intended.

Comment: I hate to say that it has never happened to me, but then I don't deal with yaml or json in Visual Studio and at least it handles xml without much difficulty.  I wish I could help you.